# How to count items in List with ImmutableJS?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutable.js

I have a List which looks like this:

```
["green", "blue","green","green", "blue", "black"]
```

How can I use the ImmutableJS operators to count these items and get a Map which could look like this:

```
{ green: {name: green, count: 3}, blue:{name: blue, count: 2}, black:{name: black, count: 1}}
```

I found the following function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313268/find-the-number-of-occurrences-a-given-value-has-in-an-array/17313444#17313444) to do just that in plain JS, so how could I achieve this with ImmutableJS?

```
export const countOccurances = obj => {

   return obj
        .reduce((counter, x) =>  {

            if (counter.hasOwnProperty(x)) { 
                counter[x].count = counter[x].count + 1
            } else {
                counter[x] =  {name: x, count: 1}
            }
            return counter;

        }, {})
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `groupBy` followed by `map`. Something like this:

```
list.groupBy(elem => elem).map(arr => {
    return  {"name" : arr.get(0), "count": arr.size }
})
```

`list.groupBy(elem => elem)` will return a `KeyedSeq` with the color String as it's key and an `Iterable` of Strings as value. It would look like this in pure JS.

```
{ green: ["green","green","green"], blue:["blue","blue"], black: ["black"]}
```

We can then map these to return the size of the iterable as well as the name and we should get what you wanted:

```
{ green: {name: "green", count: 3}, blue:{name: "blue", count: 2}, black:{name: "black", count: 1}}
```

Of course if you wanted to get exactly that, you would need to use `toJS()` at the end.

Comment: Thank you! Hope @ThorbenA does the same! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a mixed solution:

```
list.toJS().length
```