# Find all occurrences of word in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the number of total occurrences of a word in an array.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313444/1170330) I found a solution and altered it a bit:

```
var dataset = ["word", "a word", "another word"];
var search = "word";
var count = dataset.reduce(function(n, val) {
  return n + (val === search);
}, 0);
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx0adw6c/).

But, instead of 3 I only get 1. So it only finds the first element, which is just `word`. But how to find all elements, containing `word`?

Comment: `return n + (val.indexOf(search) >= 0);`

Comment: Can you please answer whether you want this to count ["word times three word word", "word"]` as four occurrences, or just 2? If it should be four, this actually becomes a bit more complex than most of the answers that have been given.

Comment: @Katana314: In my case there won't be multiple occurrences of a word within an element of an array.

Comment: My apologies, then, to the answerer that I downvoted. (Pretty much every answer had that issue, at which point I decided to clarify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dataset = ["word", "a word", "another word"];
var search = "word";
count = 0;

jQuery(dataset).each(function(i, v){ if(v.indexOf(search) != -1) {count ++} });
```

Here, `count` will be 3.

Comment: Why did you switch to using jQuery.each?

Comment: This actually wouldn't account for `["word is word present word multiple word times word", "word"]`

Comment: @Katana314 As OP says in comments, it won't repeat the search string for him.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) that return the index of the first occurence of the substring in the string, or `-1` if not found:

```
var dataset = ["word", "a word", "another word"];
var search = "word";
var count = dataset.reduce(function(n, val) {
  return n + (val.indexOf(search) > -1 ? 1 : 0);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator === means: equal object and equal type.

If you are looking for each array element containing the 'search' word you need to use a different operator.

So, another possible approach, using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), is:

```js
var dataset = ["word", "a word", "another word"];
var search = "word";
var count = dataset.filter(function(val) {
  return val.indexOf(search) != -1;
}).length;

document.write('N. words: ' + count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```js
var dataset = ["word", "a word", "another word"],
    search = "word",
    count = dataset.reduce(function(r, a) {
        return r + !!~a.indexOf(search);
    }, 0);

document.write(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **one-line ES6 Arrow Function**.

```
 const  countOccurrence = (arr,elem) =>  arr.filter((v) => v===elem).length;
```

> **Testing**

```js
const  countOccurrence = (arr,elem) =>  arr.filter((v) => v===elem).length;

//Testing
console.log(countOccurrence([1,2,3,4,5,6,1,8,9,1,1],1));
console.log(countOccurrence(['w','o','w'],'w'));
console.log(countOccurrence(['hello','world','hello'],'hello'));
```