# JavaScript code to get count of occurrence of objects in array of objects using array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, array-reduce

```
var developers = [
    { name: "Joe", age: 23 ,overallLevel: "high"},
    { name: "Sue", age: 28 ,overallLevel: "advanced" },
    { name: "Jon", age: 32 ,overallLevel: "high" },
    { name: "Bob", age: 24 ,overallLevel: "high" },
    { name: "Bob", age: 20 ,overallLevel: "advanced" }
]
```

Need count of overallLevel in the mentioned array using array.reduce()
 [high:3, advanced:2]

Comment: What have you tried already? What issues are you facing? Generally speaking `Fix this for me` questions don't go down too well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rdw26c3k/

Comment: You could use filter() and just pass value of overallLevel to filter by. Than you could just count items in filtered array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the number of occurrences a given value has in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313268/find-the-number-of-occurrences-a-given-value-has-in-an-array)

Comment: please have a look to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

You could just count them with an object.

```js
var developers = [{ name: "Joe", age: 23, overallLevel: "high" }, { name: "Sue", age: 28, overallLevel: "advanced" }, { name: "Jon", age: 32, overallLevel: "high" }, { name: "Bob", age: 24, overallLevel: "high" }, { name: "Bob", age: 20, overallLevel: "advanced" }],
    overallLevel = developers.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.overallLevel] = (r[a.overallLevel] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(overallLevel);
```

Comment: Could you tell us how `(r[a.overallLevel] || 0) + 1;` will evaluate

Comment: @SandeepNayak `r[a.overallLevel] || 0` will assign zero should `r[a.overallLevel]` be a fasly value. It will then add one to it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (**you need no `array.reduce()` to do that**):

```js
var
  i,
  count = {high: 0, advanced: 0},
  developers = [
    { name: "Joe", age: 23 ,overallLevel: "high"},
    { name: "Sue", age: 28 ,overallLevel: "advanced" },
    { name: "Jon", age: 32 ,overallLevel: "high" },
    { name: "Bob", age: 24 ,overallLevel: "high" },
    { name: "Bob", age: 20 ,overallLevel: "advanced" }
  ];

for (i in developers) {

  count[developers[i].overallLevel]++;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(count)); //  Object { high=3,  advanced=2}
```