# JavaScript code to fetch range of dates from array of objects depending on one attribute of the array using array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-reduce

```
var developers = [
{ name: "Joe", age: 23, overallLevel: "high", date: "Aug 14, 2015" },
{ name: "Sue", age: 28, overallLevel: "advanced", date: "Aug 11, 2015" },
{ name: "Jon", age: 32, overallLevel: "high", date: "Aug 10, 2015" },
{ name: "Bob", age: 24, overallLevel: "high", date: "Sept 07, 2015" },
{ name: "Johnson", age: 23, overallLevel: "advanced", date: "Aug 20, 2015" },
{ name: "Paul", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Jan 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Jane", age: 27, overallLevel: "intermediate", date: "Aug 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Chris", age: 20, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Aug 1, 2016" },
{ name: "Susan", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Dec 12, 2015" },
{ name: "Jenny", age: 23, overallLevel: "intermediate", date: "Aug 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Stone", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "June 13, 2016" },
]
```

Following is the data extracted from array which indicates levels followed by their dates.

"high" :
Aug 10, 2015,
Aug 14, 2015,
Sept 07, 2015

"advanced" :
Aug 11, 2015,
Aug 20, 2015

"basic" :
Jan 30, 2016,
Aug 1, 2016,
Dec 12, 2015,
June 13, 2016,

"intermediate" :
Aug 30, 2016,
Aug 30, 2016

Expected output: Require the range of min and max date i.e shown further

{
high : Aug 10, 2015 - Sept 07,2015,
advanced : Aug 11, 2015 - Aug 20,2015,
basic : Dec 12, 2015 - Aug 1,2016,
intermediate : Jan 30,2016
}

This is what i was able to get the count of overallLevel for grouping purpose.

```
var developers = [
{ name: "Joe", age: 23, overallLevel: "high", date: "Aug 14, 2015" },
{ name: "Sue", age: 28, overallLevel: "advanced", date: "Aug 11, 2015" },
{ name: "Jon", age: 32, overallLevel: "high", date: "Aug 10, 2015" },
{ name: "Bob", age: 24, overallLevel: "high", date: "Sept 07, 2015" },
{ name: "Johnson", age: 23, overallLevel: "advanced", date: "Aug 20, 2015" },
{ name: "Paul", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Jan 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Jane", age: 27, overallLevel: "intermediate", date: "Aug 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Chris", age: 20, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Aug 1, 2016" },
{ name: "Susan", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Dec 12, 2015" },
{ name: "Jenny", age: 23, overallLevel: "intermediate", date: "Aug 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Stone", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "June 13, 2016" },
],
    overallLevel = developers.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.overallLevel] = (r[a.overallLevel] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(overallLevel);
```

Please visit this :
https://jsfiddle.net/Saily/6nzxd6ss/

Comment: Where is your script ? You are suppose to share your efforts as well..

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Output should show the level name and dates range across those @JLRishe

Comment: Effort is shared @Rayon

Comment: @SailyJadhav, I am unable to see _"What is not working ?"_

Comment: @SailyJadhav, This is just what [_Nina had answered_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565828/javascript-code-to-get-count-of-occurrence-of-objects-in-array-of-objects-using) ain't it ?

Comment: LOC's get reduced this is the reason to use reduce @NinaScholz

Comment: Lines of Code @NinaScholz

Comment: You have to actually put in some of your own effort. This isn't a "write code for me" site. Also, you still haven't clearly conveyed _why_ you need to use `.reduce()` for this.

Answer (score 1):

I also enjoy using reduces. It's very handy for a lot of cases.

```js
var developers = [
{ name: "Joe", age: 23, overallLevel: "high", date: "Aug 14, 2015" },
{ name: "Sue", age: 28, overallLevel: "advanced", date: "Aug 11, 2015" },
{ name: "Jon", age: 32, overallLevel: "high", date: "Aug 10, 2015" },
{ name: "Bob", age: 24, overallLevel: "high", date: "Sept 07, 2015" },
{ name: "Johnson", age: 23, overallLevel: "advanced", date: "Aug 20, 2015" },
{ name: "Paul", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Jan 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Jane", age: 27, overallLevel: "intermediate", date: "Aug 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Chris", age: 20, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Aug 1, 2016" },
{ name: "Susan", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "Dec 12, 2015" },
{ name: "Jenny", age: 23, overallLevel: "intermediate", date: "Aug 30, 2016" },
{ name: "Stone", age: 25, overallLevel: "basic", date: "June 13, 2016" },
],
reduced = developers.reduce((p,c) => {var d = new Date(c.date);
                                      p[c.overallLevel] ? d < p[c.overallLevel][0] && d < p[c.overallLevel][1] ? p[c.overallLevel][0] = d
                                                                                                               : p[c.overallLevel][1] = d
                                                        : p[c.overallLevel] = [d,d];
                                      return p},{});
reduced = Object.keys(reduced).reduce((p,c) => (p[c] = p[c].map(e => e.toDateString(2)), p),reduced);
       
console.log(reduced);
```