# How to count number of occurences of names in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects. It looks like this

```
const data = [{name: "Jeslord Thompson", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Michael Norman", house: "9", class: "3B2"},
{name: "Prince Asiedu", house: "9", class: "1D2"},
{name: "Ronald Eyeson", house: "9", class: "3D3"},
{name: "Ernest Essien", house: "9", class: "2F"},
{name: "Kalikrates", house: "9", class: "1H"},
{name: "Michael Sungnuma", house: "9", class: "2D3"},
{name: "Alidu Wonzooya", house: "9", class: "2E"},
{name: "Shadrach Achambaka", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Fidel Taylor", house: "9", class: "2P"},
{name: "Emmanuel Buabeng", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Clement Davour", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Kingsley Buadi", house: "9", class: "3N"},
{name: "Lommo", house: "9", class: "3H"},
{name: "Jeslord Thompson", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Michael Norman", house: "9", class: "3B2"},
{name: "Prince Asiedu", house: "9", class: "1D2"},
{name: "Ronald Eyeson", house: "9", class: "3D3"},
{name: "Ernest Essien", house: "9", class: "2F"},
{name: "Kalikrates", house: "9", class: "1H"},
{name: "Michael Sungnuma", house: "9", class: "2D3"},
{name: "Alidu Wonzooya", house: "9", class: "2E"},
{name: "Shadrach Achambaka", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Fidel Taylor", house: "9", class: "2P"},
{name: "Emmanuel Buabeng", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Clement Davour", house: "9", class: "2G"}]
```

What, I want is to be able to count the number of times each name appears in the array and get an
array like this for every name in the array above in this format.

`[{name: "Jeslord Thompson", count:2}]`

This is my attempt

```
names = data.map(arr => arr.name)

for(var i = 0; i< names.length; i++){
 for(var j = i+1; i<names.length; i++){
    if (names[i] === names[j]){
```

But I'm stuck, and still thinking of what to do

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: This is common use-case for [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The documentation literally includes [an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object) titled "Counting instances of values in an object" that counts the number of times a name occurs in an array.

Comment: See the MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object)

Comment: This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565828/javascript-code-to-get-count-of-occurrence-of-objects-in-array-of-objects-using

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, yes I'm trying something like this
names = data.map(arr => arr.name)

for(var i = 0; i< names.length; i++){
    for(var j = i+1; i<names.length; i++){
        if (names[i] === names[j]){

But I'm trying to figure out how to do it from here

Comment: Add the attempt in your question, maybe can take a look

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, I get {undefined: 26} when I use the code in the link you attached.

Comment: Please add to the question you code , what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [{
    name: "Jeslord Thompson",
    house: "9",
    class: "2G"
  },
  {
    name: "Michael Norman",
    house: "9",
    class: "3B2"
  },
  {
    name: "Prince Asiedu",
    house: "9",
    class: "1D2"
  },
  {
    name: "Ronald Eyeson",
    house: "9",
    class: "3D3"
  },
  {
    name: "Ernest Essien",
    house: "9",
    class: "2F"
  },
  {
    name: "Kalikrates",
    house: "9",
    class: "1H"
  },
  {
    name: "Michael Sungnuma",
    house: "9",
    class: "2D3"
  },
  {
    name: "Alidu Wonzooya",
    house: "9",
    class: "2E"
  },
  {
    name: "Shadrach Achambaka",
    house: "9",
    class: "2G"
  },
  {
    name: "Fidel Taylor",
    house: "9",
    class: "2P"
  },
  {
    name: "Emmanuel Buabeng",
    house: "9",
    class: "2G"
  },
  {
    name: "Clement Davour",
    house: "9",
    class: "2G"
  },
  {
    name: "Kingsley Buadi",
    house: "9",
    class: "3N"
  },
  {
    name: "Lommo",
    house: "9",
    class: "3H"
  },
  {
    name: "Jeslord Thompson",
    house: "9",
    class: "2G"
  },
  {
    name: "Michael Norman",
    house: "9",
    class: "3B2"
  },
  {
    name: "Prince Asiedu",
    house: "9",
    class: "1D2"
  },
  {
    name: "Ronald Eyeson",
    house: "9",
    class: "3D3"
  },
  {
    name: "Ernest Essien",
    house: "9",
    class: "2F"
  },
  {
    name: "Kalikrates",
    house: "9",
    class: "1H"
  },
  {
    name: "Michael Sungnuma",
    house: "9",
    class: "2D3"
  },
  {
    name: "Alidu Wonzooya",
    house: "9",
    class: "2E"
  },
  {
    name: "Shadrach Achambaka",
    house: "9",
    class: "2G"
  },
  {
    name: "Fidel Taylor",
    house: "9",
    class: "2P"
  },
  {
    name: "Emmanuel Buabeng",
    house: "9",
    class: "2G"
  },
  {
    name: "Clement Davour",
    house: "9",
    class: "2G"
  }
]

let result = [];

data.forEach((item) => {
  let resultData = {
    name: item.name,
    count: 0
  }
  let count = data.filter((contact) => {
    return contact.name === item.name;
  });
  resultData.count = count.length;
  result.push(resultData);
});

console.log(result);
```

Please support with marked as answer if it helps you, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the structure for each name as property of the new object and then [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to convert it to an array.

```js
let arr = [{name: "Jeslord Thompson", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Michael Norman", house: "9", class: "3B2"},
{name: "Prince Asiedu", house: "9", class: "1D2"},
{name: "Ronald Eyeson", house: "9", class: "3D3"},
{name: "Ernest Essien", house: "9", class: "2F"},
{name: "Kalikrates", house: "9", class: "1H"},
{name: "Michael Sungnuma", house: "9", class: "2D3"},
{name: "Alidu Wonzooya", house: "9", class: "2E"},
{name: "Shadrach Achambaka", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Fidel Taylor", house: "9", class: "2P"},
{name: "Emmanuel Buabeng", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Clement Davour", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Kingsley Buadi", house: "9", class: "3N"},
{name: "Lommo", house: "9", class: "3H"},
{name: "Jeslord Thompson", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Michael Norman", house: "9", class: "3B2"},
{name: "Prince Asiedu", house: "9", class: "1D2"},
{name: "Ronald Eyeson", house: "9", class: "3D3"},
{name: "Ernest Essien", house: "9", class: "2F"},
{name: "Kalikrates", house: "9", class: "1H"},
{name: "Michael Sungnuma", house: "9", class: "2D3"},
{name: "Alidu Wonzooya", house: "9", class: "2E"},
{name: "Shadrach Achambaka", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Fidel Taylor", house: "9", class: "2P"},
{name: "Emmanuel Buabeng", house: "9", class: "2G"},
{name: "Clement Davour", house: "9", class: "2G"}];

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {name}) => {
    if (acc[name] === undefined)
        acc[name] = {name: name, count: 1};
    else
        acc[name].count++;
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```