# number of occurences of all values in an array as text to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

The accepted answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313268/idiomatically-find-the-number-of-occurrences-a-given-value-has-in-an-array) very elegantly logs the number of occurrences of all values in a given array to the console. When I try to set this as a value of an input or as the text of a div it only gives the last value of the array.

I can't figure it out. Excuse my noobness.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  class Counter extends Map {
    constructor(iter, key = null) {
      super();
      this.key = key || (x => x);
      for (let x of iter) {
        this.add(x);
      }
    }

    add(x) {
      x = this.key(x);
      this.set(x, (this.get(x) || 0) + 1);
    }
  }

  results = new Counter(["john", "mark", "George", "mark", "john", "George", "john", "George", "bill"]);
  for (let [number, times] of results.entries())
    $("div").text(times + "x " + number)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<button>LOG</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: The problem is because you're ***overwriting*** the `text()` each time you call it. Change it to `append()` (and add a little styling) and the code works fine.

Comment: append adds it every time i call it,is there any way to just update it ?

Comment: call `$("div").text('')` before the `for` loop

Comment: Or just `empty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration you are overriding the element's text, as a result only the final text is shown. You should store the text in a variable and use that:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {

  class Counter extends Map {
      constructor(iter, key=null) {
          super();
          this.key = key || (x => x);
          for (let x of iter) {
              this.add(x);
          }
      }
      add(x) {
        x = this.key(x);
        this.set(x, (this.get(x) || 0) + 1);
      }
  }

  var res = "";
  results = new Counter(["john", "mark", "George", "mark", "john", "George", "john", "George", "bill"]);
  for (let [number, times] of results.entries()){
    res += times + "x " + number;
  }
  $("div").text(res);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>LOG</button>
<div></div>
```